# Javascript - redirect parent window from popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, popup

I have a problem in my javascript, I will explain myself:
I open two popups for content loading purposes for a CRM.
Once these two popups finished loading (and they are heavy) I close them.
But now, I need to redirect the parent page to a URL defined at the beginning after the two popups were closed.

The problem is that I never manage to redirect the parent window after the two popup were closed... I tried everything that I could find ...

Here is the code of my last try:

```
var test = $("#blob_detailView_moreAction_LBL_DUPLICATE > a").attr('href');
    $("#blob_detailView_moreAction_LBL_DUPLICATE > a").attr('href', "#");

    $("#blob_detailView_moreAction_LBL_DUPLICATE").on('click', '', test, function(event){
        //on récupère l'url qu'il y avait sur dupliquer
        var data = event.data;

        var extrudedUrl = removeURLParameter(window.location.href, 'requestMode');
        extrudedUrl = removeURLParameter(extrudedUrl, 'tab_label');
        extrudedUrl = extrudedUrl.replace("#", "");
        var haut=(screen.height-100);
        var currentWindow = window.location.href;
        var impressionWindow = window.open(extrudedUrl + "&requestMode=impression", '_blank', 'resizable=no,location=no,top='+haut+',height=100,width=100,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,statusbar=no');
        var couvertureWindow = window.open(extrudedUrl + "&requestMode=couverture", '_blank', 'resizable=no,location=no,top='+haut+',height=100,width=100,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,statusbar=no');
        //$(location).attr("href", data);
        var test = $(impressionWindow).on("unload", '', data,function(){
            $(couvertureWindow).on("unload", function(){
                couvertureWindow.close();
            });
            impressionWindow.close();
        });
        test.promise().done($(location).attr("href", data));

    });
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The argument passed to `done` method should be a function or an array of functions. See [`jQuery promise`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/).

Comment: yes but that does not solve the problem

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Notice, that `location` is an object, not a HTML element, you should not wrap it into jQuery, i.e. `location.href = data;` ...

Comment: no error on console, in this case I was well redirected but too early.
i want to be redirect after the two popup were closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i do this and it's works:

```
impressionWindow.addEventListener('load', function(){
            impressionWindow.close();
        }, false);
        couvertureWindow.addEventListener('load', function(){
            couvertureWindow.close();
            window.location.href = data;
        }, false);
```